# Terminate external program run through asyncio with specific signal

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I need to terminate external programs which run from an asyncio Python script with a specific signal, say SIGTERM. My problem is that programs always receives SIGINT even if I send them SIGTERM signal.

Here is a test case, source code for a `fakeprg` used in the test below can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/thekvs/639e5e9a2e7fd31b8aff396df50e2e28).

```
import asyncio
import traceback
import os
import os.path
import sys
import time
import signal
import shlex

from functools import partial


class ExtProgramRunner:
    run = True
    processes = []

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def start(self, loop):
        self.current_loop = loop
        self.current_loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, lambda: asyncio.async(self.stop('SIGINT')))
        self.current_loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGTERM, lambda: asyncio.async(self.stop('SIGTERM')))
        asyncio.async(self.cancel_monitor())
        asyncio.Task(self.run_external_programs())

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def stop(self, sig):
        print("Got {} signal".format(sig))
        self.run = False
        for process in self.processes:
            print("sending SIGTERM signal to the process with pid {}".format(process.pid))
            process.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM)
        print("Canceling all tasks")
        for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
            task.cancel()

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def cancel_monitor(self):
        while True:
            try:
                yield from asyncio.sleep(0.05)
            except asyncio.CancelledError:
                break
        print("Stopping loop")
        self.current_loop.stop()

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def run_external_programs(self):
        os.makedirs("/tmp/files0", exist_ok=True)
        os.makedirs("/tmp/files1", exist_ok=True)
        # schedule tasks for execution
        asyncio.Task(self.run_cmd_forever("/tmp/fakeprg /tmp/files0 1000"))
        asyncio.Task(self.run_cmd_forever("/tmp/fakeprg /tmp/files1 5000"))

    @asyncio.coroutine
    def run_cmd_forever(self, cmd):
        args = shlex.split(cmd)
        while self.run:
            process = yield from asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(*args)
            self.processes.append(process)
            exit_code = yield from process.wait()
            for idx, p in enumerate(self.processes):
                if process.pid == p.pid:
                    self.processes.pop(idx)
            print("External program '{}' exited with exit code {}, relauching".format(cmd, exit_code))


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    try:
        daemon = ExtProgramRunner()
        loop.call_soon(daemon.start, loop)

        # start main event loop
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    except asyncio.CancelledError as exc:
        print("asyncio.CancelledError")
    except Exception as exc:
        print(exc, file=sys.stderr)
        print("====", file=sys.stderr)
        print(traceback.format_exc(), file=sys.stderr)
    finally:
        print("Stopping daemon...")
        loop.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this is: When you start your python program (parent) and it starts it's processes `/tmp/fakeprg` (children) they get all different processes with its pid but they all [run in the same foreground process group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group#Applications). Your shell is bound to this group, so when you hit `Ctrl-C` (`SIGINT`), `Ctrl-Y` (`SIGTSTP`) or `Ctrl-\` (`SIGQUIT`) they are sent to *all processes* in the foreground process group.

In your code this happens before the parent can even send the signal to its children through `send_signal`, so this line sends a signal to an already dead process (and should fail, so IMO that's an issue with asyncio).

To solve that, you can explicitly put your child process into a separate process group, like this:

```
asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(*args, preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)
```